# Django - Getting Related objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

There are such models:

```
class Nomenclature(models.Model):
    nameNom = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name = "Название номеклатуры")
    numNom = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name = "Номер номеклатуры",unique=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество", default=0)
    numPolk = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name = "Номер полки/места"  

class Changes(models.Model):
    numNomenclature = models.ForeignKey(Nomenclature, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="chamges",verbose_name="Номер номеклатуры")
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Количество",null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name = "Место установки")
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name = "ФИО")
    appointment = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name = "Назначение")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name='Дата/время', null=True)
```

It is necessary to output the name and number of the nomenclature and all related changes to the template, and also output all fields

I found that **select_related** exists, but I thought that it doesn't work the way I need it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you need.
If you need to fetch all of the changes, from a single "Nomenclature" model:

```
md = Nomenclature.objects.get(id=id) # Not sure how you fetch this, just an example.
all_changes_for_md = Changes.objects.filter(numNomenclature__id=md.id)
```

This will fetch you all changes for a nomenclature model.
Also possible to do it like this:

```
md = Nomenclature.objects.get(id=id) # Not sure how you fetch this, just an example.
all_changes_for_md = md.chamges.all() # You made a typo in the related name.
```

Select related has another purpose, it is used for prefetching.
From the Django docs:

> **select_related(*fields)**
> Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query ***but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.***

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related